# How do I view Facebook page suggestions?

Tags: facebook

When you like a page, a list of similar pages will be shown. I googled for it but I only found how to [turn it off](https://www.facebook.com/help/514622715244231). I had some suggestions that were great but the list just disappears when you navigate away.

How can I bring the list back?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Facebook page that you originally liked.
2. Copy the URL and paste it into the "Find your Facebook ID" tool (http://findmyfbid.com) to retrieve the numeric page ID.
3. Copy the numeric page ID, then paste it after the final equal sign in the following URL, then hit the "Enter" key:

   https://www.facebook.com/pages/?ref=page_suggestions_on_liking_refresh&frompageid=
4. You should now see all the suggested pages which you had originally seen before you navigated away.

Comment: Thanks. After clicking on "see more suggestions" this is the url `https://www.facebook.com/pages/?frompageid=[numeric page id]` seems to have the same results as the you suggested. Page id has to be numeric.

Answer (score -1):

On Mobile:

Open any page's Timeline, then view your Newsfeed. 2-3 suggestions of similar to recently viewed pages will be displayed.